# "Could not interpret optimizer identifier" error in Keras

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, keras

I got this error when I tried to modify the learning rate parameter of SGD optimizer in Keras. Did I miss something in my code or my Keras was not installed properly?

Here is my code:

```
from tensorflow.python.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.python.keras.layers import Dense, Flatten, GlobalAveragePooling2D, Activation
import keras
from keras.optimizers import SGD

model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(64, kernel_initializer='uniform', input_shape=(10,)))
model.add(Activation('softmax'))
model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer=SGD(lr=0.01), metrics= ['accuracy'])*
```

and here is the error message:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "C:\TensorFlow\Keras\ResNet-50\test_sgd.py", line 10, in 
> model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer=SGD(lr=0.01), metrics=['accuracy'])   File
> "C:\Users\nsugiant\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras_impl\keras\models.py",
> line 787, in compile
> **kwargs)   File "C:\Users\nsugiant\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras_impl\keras\engine\training.py",
> line 632, in compile
> self.optimizer = optimizers.get(optimizer)   File "C:\Users\nsugiant\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras_impl\keras\optimizers.py",
> line 788, in get
> raise ValueError('Could not interpret optimizer identifier:', identifier) ValueError: ('Could not interpret optimizer identifier:',
> <keras.optimizers.SGD object at 0x000002039B152FD0>)

Answer (score 74):

The reason is you are using `tensorflow.python.keras` API for model and layers and `keras.optimizers` for SGD. They are two different Keras versions of TensorFlow and pure Keras. They could not work together. You have to change everything to one version. Then it should work.

Comment: this doesnt work, you should give a working solution

Answer (score 25):

I am bit late here, Your issue is you have mixed Tensorflow keras and keras API in your code. The optimizer and the model should come from same layer definition.  Use Keras API for everything as below:

```
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, Dropout, LSTM, BatchNormalization
from keras.callbacks import TensorBoard
from keras.callbacks import ModelCheckpoint
from keras.optimizers import adam

# Set Model
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(128, input_shape=(train_x.shape[1:]), return_sequences=True))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(BatchNormalization())

# Set Optimizer
opt = adam(lr=0.001, decay=1e-6)

# Compile model
model.compile(
    loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',
    optimizer=opt,
    metrics=['accuracy']
)
```

I have used adam in this example. Please use your relevant optimizer as per above code.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Alternatively, if you'd like to use tensorflow.keras instead of keras, try the example at the following [link](https://keras.io/api/optimizers/)

Answer (score 17):

This problem is mainly caused due to different versions. The tensorflow.keras version may not be same as the keras.
Thus causing the error as mentioned by @Priyanka.

For me, whenever this error arises, I pass in the name of the optimizer as a string, and the backend figures it out.
For example instead of

```
tf.keras.optimizers.Adam
```

or

```
keras.optimizers.Adam
```

I do

```
model.compile(optimizer= 'adam' , loss= keras.losses.binary_crossentropy, metrics=['accuracy'])
```

Comment: Yes, you can pass a string name of the optimizer as the value of optimizer argument but using tf.keras.optimizers.Adam function is more flexible when you want to adjust optimizer setting for example learning rate.

Comment: Just to add, in current TF version (2.4.1), optimizers have to be called as a function, not a parameter. So the exact code will be "tf.keras.optimizers.Adam()"

Comment: then how can I add lr with this syntax? i tried below but it did not work

model.compile(optimizer= 'adam'(lr=0.0001);
                         loss= keras.losses.binary_crossentropy,
                         metrics=['accuracy'])

Answer (score 6):

```
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import SGD
```

This works well.

Since Tensorflow 2.0, there is a new API available directly via `tensorflow`:

- https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2019/10/21/keras-vs-tf-keras-whats-the-difference-in-tensorflow-2-0/

Solution works for `tensorflow==2.2.0rc2`, `Keras==2.2.4` (on Win10)

Please also note that the version above uses `learning_rate` as parameter and no longer `lr`.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Answer (score 5):

For some libraries (e.g. `keras_radam`) you'll need to set up an environment variable before the import:

```
import os
os.environ['TF_KERAS'] = '1'

import tensorflow
import your_library
```

Answer (score 5):

In my case it was because I missed the parentheses. I am using tensorflow_addons so my code was like

```
model.compile(optimizer=tfa.optimizers.LAMB, loss='binary_crossentropy',
              metrics=['binary_accuracy'])
```

And it gives

`ValueError: ('Could not interpret optimizer identifier:', <class tensorflow_addons.optimizers.lamb.LAMB'>)`

Then I changed my code into:

```
model.compile(optimizer=tfa.optimizers.LAMB(), loss='binary_crossentropy',
              metrics=['binary_accuracy'])
```

and it works.

Answer (score 5):

recently, in the latest update of Keras API 2.5.0 , importing Adam optimizer shows the following error:

```
from keras.optimizers import Adam
ImportError: cannot import name 'Adam' from 'keras.optimizers'
```

instead use the following for importing optimizers (i.e. Adam) :

```
from keras.optimizers import adam_v2
optimizer = adam_v2.Adam(learning_rate=lr, decay=lr/epochs)
Model.compile(loss='--',  optimizer=optimizer  , metrics=['--'])
```

Answer (score 4):

Running the Keras documentaion example https://keras.io/examples/cifar10_cnn/
and installing the latest keras and tensor flow versions

(at the time of this writing 
tensorflow           2.0.0a0  and Keras version  2.2.4 )

I had to  import explicitly the optimizer the keras the example is using,specifically the line on top of the example :

```
opt = tensorflow.keras.optimizers.rmsprop(lr=0.0001, decay=1e-6)
```

was replaced by

```
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import RMSprop

opt = RMSprop(lr=0.0001, decay=1e-6)
```

In the recent version the api "broke" and keras.stuff in a lot of cases became tensorflow.keras.stuff.

Answer (score 3):

Use one style in one kernel, try not to mix

`from keras.optimizers import sth`

with

`from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import sth`

Answer (score 2):

I tried the following and it worked for me:

from keras import optimizers

sgd = optimizers.SGD(lr=0.01)

model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer=sgd)

Answer (score 2):

use

> from tensorflow.keras import optimizers

instead of

> from keras import optimizers

Answer (score 1):

Try changing your import lines to

```
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, ...
```

Your imports seem a little strange to me. Maybe you could elaborate more on that.

Answer (score 1):

I have misplaced parenthesis and got this error,

Initially it was

```
x=Conv2D(filters[0],(3,3),use_bias=False,padding="same",kernel_regularizer=l2(reg),x))
```

The corrected version was

```
x=Conv2D(filters[0],(3,3),use_bias=False,padding="same",kernel_regularizer=l2(reg))(x)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just give

```
optimizer = 'sgd' / 'RMSprop'
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Could you add a little bit of an explanation about why you think this would solve the problem stated in the question?

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error message and resolved this issue, in my case, by replacing the assignment of optimizer:

```
optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adam
```

with its instance instead of the class itself:

```
optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adam()
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried everything in this thread to fix it but they didn't work. However, I managed to fix it for me. For me, the issue was that calling the optimizer class, ie. `tensorflow.keras.optimizers.Adam` caused the error, but calling the optimizer as a function, ie. `tensorflow.keras.optimizers.Adam()` worked. So my code looks like:

```
model.compile(
    loss=tensorflow.keras.losses.categorical_crossentropy(),
    optimizer=tensorflow.keras.optimizers.Adam()
)
```

Looking at the tensorflow github, [I am not the only one with this error where calling the function rather than the class fixed the error.](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/19913#issuecomment-613732704)

Answer (score 0):

This also happens in `keras_core` (the new library which will soon turn to Keras 3.0 (solution provided in the 2 comments ## below, TLDR : change the optimizer from `keras.optimizers.x.y.z` to `tf.keras.optimizers.x.y.z.`

In the following code snippet:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import keras_cv
import tensorflow_datasets as tfds
import keras_core as keras

# Create a preprocessing pipeline with augmentations
BATCH_SIZE = 16
NUM_CLASSES = 3
augmenter = keras_cv.layers.Augmenter(
    [
        keras_cv.layers.RandomFlip(),
        keras_cv.layers.RandAugment(value_range=(0, 255)),
        keras_cv.layers.CutMix(),
    ],
)

def preprocess_data(images, labels, augment=False):
    labels = tf.one_hot(labels, NUM_CLASSES)
    inputs = {"images": images, "labels": labels}
    outputs = inputs
    if augment:
        outputs = augmenter(outputs)
    return outputs['images'], outputs['labels']

train_dataset, test_dataset = tfds.load(
    'rock_paper_scissors',
    as_supervised=True,
    split=['train', 'test'],
)
train_dataset = train_dataset.batch(BATCH_SIZE).map(
    lambda x, y: preprocess_data(x, y, augment=True),
        num_parallel_calls=tf.data.AUTOTUNE).prefetch(
            tf.data.AUTOTUNE)
test_dataset = test_dataset.batch(BATCH_SIZE).map(
    preprocess_data, num_parallel_calls=tf.data.AUTOTUNE).prefetch(
        tf.data.AUTOTUNE)

# Create a model using a pretrained backbone
backbone = keras_cv.models.EfficientNetV2Backbone.from_preset(
    "efficientnetv2_b0_imagenet"
)
model = keras_cv.models.ImageClassifier(
    backbone=backbone,
    num_classes=NUM_CLASSES,
    activation="softmax",
)
model.compile(
    loss='categorical_crossentropy',
    #Here lies the problem, need to convert it to tf.keras.optimizers.Adam as below
    #Instead of pure keras.optimizers.Adam()
    optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=1e-5),
    metrics=['accuracy']
)

# Train your model
model.fit(
    train_dataset,
    validation_data=test_dataset,
    epochs=8,
    verbose=1
)
```