# TerminatedWorkerError: A worker process managed by the executor was unexpectedly terminated

Tags: python-3.x, keras, deep-learning, anaconda

I am trying to find optimal hyperparameters for my Deep learning model. When I used 'GridSearchCV' approach and tried fitting my model, I ended up with error

> "TerminatedWorkerError: A worker process managed by the executor was unexpectedly terminated. This could be caused by a segmentation fault while calling the function or by an excessive memory usage causing the Operating System to kill the worker. The exit codes of the workers are {EXIT(1)}"

I have updated and tested scipy libraries, and that works fine.
I can't use n_jobs=-1. I must use 1 upto 16 CPUs (n_jobs=16).

My platform:
NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION="16.04.6 LTS (Xenial Xerus)".
I am accessing sklearn using conda 4.7.12 in python 3.6.9.
We can't update Ubuntu at this time!

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy
import keras
import scipy
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
from keras.wrappers.scikit_learn import KerasClassifier
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from keras.optimizers import SGD
from sklearn.externals import joblib
from math import sqrt
import tensorflow as tf
from datetime import datetime


# Make grid input
batch_size  = [1644, 822, 548, 411, 328, 274, 234, 205, 182, 164]
epochs = [10, 50, 100, 150, 200, 250, 300]
learn_rate = [0.00001, 0.0001, 0.001, 0.01, 0.1, 0.2, 0.3]
momentum = [0.0, 0.2, 0.4, 0.6, 0.8, 0.9]
param_grid = dict(epochs = epochs, batch_size = batch_size, learn_rate=learn_rate, momentum=momentum)

# Define model
def get_compiled_model_advanced(learn_rate=learn_rate, momentum=momentum):
    model = tf.keras.Sequential([
        tf.keras.layers.Dense(200, activation='relu'),
        tf.keras.layers.Dense(50, activation='relu'),
        tf.keras.layers.Dense(10, activation='relu'),
        tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')])
    # Compile model
    optimizer = SGD(lr=learn_rate, momentum=momentum, decay=0.5, nesterov=False)
    model.compile(optimizer=optimizer, loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
    return model

model_sgd = KerasClassifier(build_fn=get_compiled_model_advanced, verbose=0)

grid_sgd = GridSearchCV(estimator = model_sgd, param_grid = param_grid, n_jobs = 16, verbose=0)
sgd_fit = grid_sgd.fit(X, Y)
```

I would like to get my model running!
Could someone tell me what am I doing wrong?

Comment: I found the problem! I was using tensorflow.python.keras api for model and layers and keras.optimizers for SGD. Now I made it all in single version!

Comment: refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50056356/could-not-interpret-optimizer-identifier-error-in-keras

Answer (score 11):

If your machine does not allow to run jobs in parallel, it throws an exception as you got. 'n_jobs=None' might fix the problem as mentioned here: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.GridSearchCV.html

Comment: Thank you! ran into this issue when trying to run `pyldavis.gensim_models.prepare`, and setting `n_jobs=1` was the answer!

Answer (score 2):

I was having the same issue and this solved my problem:

There is a `pre_dispatch` parameter defined for CV searches on sklearn and it can be set to an *int*.
For example `pre_dispatch = 2` means a total of 2 jobs are spawned during parallel execution.

Check out [sklearn GridSearchCV documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.GridSearchCV.html)!