# could anyone help me on compile error: Adam/ SGD/ RMSprop

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

if my code like this:

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

from keras.models import Sequential

from keras.layers import Dropout, Flatten, Dense, Conv2D, MaxPooling2D, BatchNormalization

from keras.callbacks import TensorBoard

from keras.callbacks import ModelCheckpoint

from keras.optimizers import Adam

from keras.optimizers import SGD
```

then it report me the error is:

ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)

```
<ipython-input-13-65309f3d78a9> in <module>()
      6 from keras.callbacks import TensorBoard
      7 from keras.callbacks import ModelCheckpoint
----> 8 from keras.optimizers import Adam
      9 from keras.optimizers import SGD
     10
```

ImportError: cannot import name 'Adam'

if my code like that:

```
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import Adam


model.compile(loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',optimizer=Adam(),metrics=['acc'])
```

it reports the error:

```
~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/optimizers.py in get(identifier)
    else:
        raise ValueError('Could not interpret optimizer identifier: {}'.format(identifier))
ValueError: Could not interpret optimizer identifier: <tensorflow.python.keras.optimizer_v2.adam.Adam object at 0x7fa9bd68c048>
```

Answer (score 1):

The import statement looks fine:

```
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import Adam
```

The compile method has three parameters (loss, optimizer and metrics). Optimizer can be a string . For example:

```
model.compile(loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',optimizer='adam',metrics=['acc'])
```

You can also specify Adam as a variable and use that variable as your optimizer:

```
example = Adam(learning_rate=0.1)
model.compile(loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',optimizer=example,metrics=['acc'])
```

The default values for Adam are [here](https://keras.io/api/optimizers/adam/).

Comment: According to your solution, I run the code like: from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import Adam
example = Adam(learning_rate=0.1)
model.compile(loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',optimizer=example,metrics=['acc']) but it still told me error:   131   else:
    132     raise ValueError(
--> 133         'Could not interpret optimizer identifier: {}'.format(identifier))

ValueError: Could not interpret optimizer identifier: <tensorflow.python.keras.optimizer_v2.adam.Adam object at 0x7efbbd646470>

Comment: That's odd. It should work. Did you check your keras version between tensorflow and keras. They are different keras. Check this out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50056356/could-not-interpret-optimizer-identifier-error-in-keras